# Eclipse: Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 2.3

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

```
Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 2.3.   MyProject       line 1  Maven Java EE Configuration Problem
```

I tried all the possible solution but i am not able to get rid of this error.

**Trick 1**

`Project Facet-> Dynamic Web Module 3.0` is selected, several time enabled disabled

**Trick 2**

also tried to changes directly

```
.settings -> org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml file
```

here are the contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="3.0"/>
  <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
  <installed facet="java" version="1.7"/>
</faceted-project>
```

Here are the contents in the **pom.xml** file (build tag only)

```
<build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java-version}</source>
                        <target>${java-version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
```

and java version is `<java-version>1.7</java-version>`

contents in **web.xml** are as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">
</web-app>
```

**Trick 3**

Right Click on project-> Maven -> Update Project and "Force update of Snapshots/Releases"

Restarted several time, both web server and eclipse itself. but its not working

The strange thing is why its looking for Dynamic Web Module **2.3**, as per my configuration it should be 3.0

Comment: Ensure the web.xml is correctly specifying 3.0, and then delete and reimport the project.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug in the Eclipse.
Try to do this:

```
1) Click on Project->Properties->Project Facets - Change Java to 1.5, uncheck Dynamic web module and click ok.
2) Check your pom.xml and find build. Change configuration to 1.7
3) Go to maven -> Update Project. 
4) Change Dynamic web module to 3.0
```

See [here](http://findnerd.com/list/view/Error-Cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-Dynamic-Web-Module-to-2-3/15855/)

Comment: Now its not allowing me to reset to 3.0
`Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.0.`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for those who might come to this page later. This problem with eclipse and maven is faced by many. The best way to create a webapp project with maven in eclipse is by yourself. Do not select any particular archetype or configuration. First, check create simple project(skip archetype selection). Select packaging to war on the next page. Then, add WEB-INF/web.xml in src/main/webapp. In the web.xml file, set your preferred web app version with the proper attributes(check the internet for this). Set the compiler version in POM.xml. Then, right click on project->maven->update project.This will set all the project facets,build path and compiler settings for the project.

Create simple project:

[image: FirstStep]

Select packaging:

[image: SecondStep]

web.xml:

[image: ThirdStep]

POM.xml:

[image: FourthStep]